# strcmp inside kernel module crash

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module, strcmp, netfilter

I am trying to to detect the a outgoing packets in my kernel(Netfilter) module. I am using a strcmp function to achieve it. The kernel always crashes after loading my kernel module with strcmp function. I tried removing the strcmp function - loaded without any problem. I hope the problem is with all string function, I also tried strstr() - my system crashed

The logic behind this, Incoming packet will have eth[0-9]+ assigned to "in->name" and "out->name" will be  and vice-versa for outgoing packet.

Any insight to detect a outgoing packet? I knew another option is to use output_hook instead of prerouting and postrouting hook. But here I want to mangle both incoming and outgoing packet in different way. Does the kernel version I am using doesn't support string function inside modules?

```
$ uname -a
Linux vmdsk01 2.6.32-21-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 16 08:09:38 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Include Part

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>

#include <linux/netfilter.h>
#include <linux/netfilter_ipv4.h>

#include <linux/skbuff.h>
#include <linux/inet.h>
#include <linux/ip.h>
#include <linux/tcp.h>
#include <net/ip.h>

#include <linux/string.h>
```

Main Hook

```
31 unsigned int main_hook(unsigned int hooknum,  
32                   struct sk_buff *skb,
33                   const struct net_device *in,
34                   const struct net_device *out,
35                   int (*okfn)(struct sk_buff*))
36 {
37     if( strcmp(out->name, "<NULL>") == NULL ) // Outgoing packet must not have <NULL>
38     {
39         printk( KERN_INFO "OUTGOING PACKET");
40     }
41     ....
```

I also tried replacing line 37 with following, my system hangs

```
37     if( strstr(out->name, "eth") != NULL ) // Outgoing packet must have eth[0-9]+
```

Comment: Do you have any crash messages? Kernel dumps? Stack traces? Logs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might have NULL pointer in `out` struct pointer. You may add some sanity checks in main_hook like:

```
unsigned int main_hook(unsigned int hooknum,  
                   struct sk_buff *skb,
                   const struct net_device *in,
                   const struct net_device *out,
                   int (*okfn)(struct sk_buff*))
 {
     if (!out)
         return -EINVAL;

     if( strncmp(out->name, "<NULL>", IFNAMSIZ) == 0 ) // Outgoing packet must not have <NULL>
     {
         printk( KERN_INFO "OUTGOING PACKET");
     }
     ....
```

So I've added check for `out` pointer and using `strncmp` instead of `strcmp` where `IFNAMSIZ` is size of `out->name` as defined in [include/linux/netdevice.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/netdevice.h?v=2.6.32#L651). Also, `str(n)cmp` does not return `NULL`, it returns `0`.

Check it and please provide any crash messages.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your source - the kernel doesn't crash :), but all the packets getting lost. I could not able to open any service(http,ftp,ssh,etc) via this pc.

Comment: Of course your packets are lost, you returns `-EINVAL` because your `out` pointer is NULL. I can't tell you if it's normal because I don't know your code. Think for yourself and come back with questions about netfilter hooks and why kernel is giving you NULL `out` pointer. For this question you should accept answer and move on.

Comment: Thanks, I understood `out` pointer is not always NULL, whenever a packet is seen by Netfilter framework, the `out` pointer is available. Your answer gave me the clue :)

Answer (score 1):

I understood the issue, the hook function is sequence of iterations like while(1) checking for packet. A iteration may or may not received a packet. If an iteration received a packet, the struct "out" would be available and its members could be accessible; I made a mistake by trying to access a member without checking availability of struct.

The following code fixed the purpose and working fine.

```
if(out)
{
    if( strcmp(out->name, "<NULL>") ) // Outgoing packet must not have <NULL>
    {
        printk( KERN_INFO "Outgoing Packet");
    }
}
```